# Registering nameservers with network solutions / Verisign

Tags: azure, nameserver, dns-hosting

I've been asking alot of questions about setting up public nameservers lately. I think I've finally got the servers setup so I went to network solutions (my registrar) to point my domain name to my new DNS Servers.

When I tried to do this, network solutions told me that the nameservers don't exist. I called tech support who told me that I must register the nameservers with verisign. The steps for that are listed:

http://www.networksolutions.com/support/how-to-register-a-dns-server-or-edit-a-dns-server-i-ve-already-registered/

**Is This normal behaviour, why would I have to do this?**

So i followed the steps. At which point, the system told me that I couldn't register my nameservers because they do not end in .mydomain.com. **Is this unusual?**

So here's my question: My DNS servers are provided a DNS Name from azure. Something like: myVM.cloudpp.net or something. Why can't I use that DNS Name as my name server?? **Do I need to create a CNAME in my current DNS as follows: ns1.mydomain.com IN CNAME myVM.cloudapp.net?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, the steps for registering your own custom name servers varies from provider is necessary , otherwise DNS queries for your domain name will not be forwarded to your name servers.

> Is This normal behaviour, why would I have to do this?

Yes, If you want to host a Name server on Azure, it’s necessary. You must set custom DNS server in your domain provider. Otherwise DNS queries for your domain name will not be forwarded to your name servers.

> So i followed the steps. At which point, the system told me that I
>   couldn't register my nameservers because they do not end in
>   .mydomain.com. Is this unusual? Do I need to create a CNAME in my
>   current DNS as follows: ns1.mydomain.com IN CNAME myVM.cloudapp.net?

Due to cloudapp.net is a domain which Azure has and Azure is not a DNS provider , so you can not own this domain. You need register a domain for your DNS server. **You must provide your own domain as your dns name. You can provide  Name Server just like ‘ns1.my domain.com’ and ‘ns2.mydomain.com’. And then put IP address for your new DNS server**. You can do this  just following the links which the support gave you.

More about How to host your public DNS server on Azure, refer to this [article](http://www.microsoftnow.com/2013/10/hosting-your-public-dns-servers-on-windows-azure.html).

Answer (score 1):

From a pure domain name registration perspective and how delegation works in DNS:

It's normal to have to separately register/manage the nameserver names and IP addresses specifically when these names are inside your own zone. This is because that's the situation when glue records need to be provided as part of the delegation.
If, on the other hand, the nameserver names are not inside your zone, it's not normal to have to do this.

Which ties in perfectly with the next problem you encountered, you are indeed not supposed to (and not allowed to) register nameserver names that are not inside your own zone.

As for why the name you attempted to use (the one ending in cloudapp.net) was not accepted, I am not so sure. I suppose there is some policy (not really a technical requirement) that the nameserver names used with `com` domains have glue.

If you get around the problem by creating names inside your own zone to use as nameservers (and in that case also registering them), do not use `CNAME` records. `NS` records are supposed to refer directly to names with address records (`A`/`AAAA`).